# Brother MFC-L9570CDW misprints when printing over WiFi using automatically installed driver

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing

I tried to use a Brother MFC-L9570CDW as a network printer in a co-working location. When I log into the local WiFi network, Ubuntu automatically installs the printer driver and shows a notification "printer added".

When I try to use the printer to print a document from LibreOffice, many pages of misprints containing seemingly random ASCII characters are printed. When I save the same document as a PDF file and send it to a Windows user, they can print the same document as expected on the same printer.

I researched the internet, including askubuntu and Brother support forums for a solution. The only similarly related [Brother support issue](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcl9570cdw_us_eu_as&faqid=faq00100729_000) suggests to install a patch file `dpkg -i brotherlegacyusb-1.1.0-0.all.deb` while unplugging a USB cable.

My operation system is Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with the latest Ubuntu Budgie desktop.

How to fix the printer driver for WiFi network, preferably on the client side (my local machine) as I have no administration privilege to the printer.

How to make sure that no faulty driver will be downloaded in the future? (Update: and how to prevent Ubuntu from auto installing drivers for WiFi printers anyway?)

Comment: Actually your link says to uninstall any proprietary drivers - the post suggest not installed; if so this step can be skipped-, then install the "legacyusb" patch and reconnect the cable a few seconds later, then ***install the Brother printer driver or scanner driver again***. While the patch is probably NOT needed for network, the usual Brother drivers seem to be still required (many laser Brother prints now work without additional drivers but your probably need them).

Comment: How to prevent Ubuntu from auto installing drivers for WiFi printers anyway?

Comment: Drivers are already "installed" (part of kernel), there's nothing to uninstall. Simply install the proprietary drivers from Brother, that's all.

Comment: Give `avahi-browse -rt _ipp._tcp`.